# Pass NSMutableArray to another view controller - not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have a view controller PlayerViewController, I am trying to pass a NSMutableArray: stories, to the view controller PlaylistViewController

in the PlayerViewController.h file I have

```
@class PlaylistViewController;
```

in the PlayerViewController.m file I have

```
//stories is a NSMutableArray that does have content in it
PlaylistViewController *sVC = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
    sVC.playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sVC.playSongArray = stories;
```

in the PlaylistViewController.h file I have

```
NSMutableArray *playSongArray;
```

and

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *playSongArray;
```

I also synthesize it in the .m file

But when I run the code, playSongArray in PlaylistViewController is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but the empty array you're setting playSongArray to first is a memory leak and functionally unnecessary. Where are you inspecting the contents of playSongArray in the PlaylistViewController?

Comment: You should delete this line of code: `sVC.playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` as it is not doing anything at all, and might be causing other problems (it won't cause this problem though).

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where are you reading the array exactly? Also, are you sure that the `stories` array you're passing isn't empty?

Comment: The stories array comes from an RSS feed, and I am sure, I output the title and description as it is added to the array as well as output the count, and it is not empty. I just need to pass that array to a tableview in another view, so the feed is being parsed in one view controller, then displayed in another.

Comment: Can you post the entire PlaylistViewController.h file? Most importantly, did you put the ivar decl in the ivar section? e.g., does it look like this at the top: `@interface PlaylistViewController { NSMutableArray* playSongArray; /* other ivars decls */ }

Answer (score 1):

How are you presenting this view? I've seen multiple times where I had to present the view before setting properties like this in order for them to be applied properly. It seems the the view is not full initialized until it is presented/displayed and part of the initialization process sets the properties to `nil`.

Assuming you are presenting this modally try the following order instead.

```
//stories is a NSMutableArray that does have content in it
PlaylistViewController *sVC = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES]; // if modal
[self pushViewController:svc animated:YES]; // if part of a uinavigationcontroller
sVC.playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sVC.playSongArray = stories;
```

Comment: I literally did this yesterday with the code I gave you and it worked, but now it doesn't for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
sVC.playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sVC.playSongArray = stories;
```

Try

```
sVC.playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:stories];
```

If it's not working, in your `PlaylistViewController` controller, add `playSongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in `initWithNibName` function then create a function :

```
- (void)setPlaySongs:(NSArray *)songs {
[playSongArray addObjectsFromArray:songs];
}
```

and load your view controller this way :

```
PlaylistViewController *sVC = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
[sVC setPlaySongs:stories];
```

Comment: Unless you're using ARC your suggestion would result in a memory leak. His property is retain, so `sVC.playSongArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:stories];` would be a better solution and would work both under ARC and managed memory patterns.

Comment: @Jason : indeed, I forgot the 'retain' property.

Comment: @Matt : where are you using your songs array in your view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are checking the value of `playSongArray` too early. Your PlaylistViewController should look like:

```
@interface PlaylistViewContror {
  NSMutableArray *playSongArray;
}

- (id)initWithPlaySongArray:(NSMutableArray *)array;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *playSongArray;

@end

@implementation PlaylistViewContror

@synthesize playSongArray;

- (id)initWithPlaySongArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
  if (!(self = [super initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil]))
    return nil;

  playSongArray = array;

  return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  // do things with playSongArray here
}

@end
```

And then in your PlayerViewController, you just do:

```
//stories is a NSMutableArray that does have content in it
PlaylistViewController *sVC = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] initWithPlaySongArray:stories];
```

Comment: Unless you're using ARC this code is unsafe. You declared your property as retain but you didn't actually retain it or set it through the synthesized accessor. You should either `self.playSongArray = array;` or `playSongArray = [array retain];`. If you are using ARC you should replace `retain` with `strong` to make it clear.

Comment: That's correct. But everyone should be using ARC... especially for new developers and/or new projects. I'm not going to write all my code examples twice with and without ARC. `[array retain]` will fail with a compile error if ARC is enabled.

Comment: Right, so then if they're not using ARC, whether you believe they should be or not (e.g., they're a new developer working on an older codebase and don't have the luxury of converting the whole thing to ARC), you could write your examples to be safe for both. Accessing the ivar through the synthesized accessor would work for both cases and changing your property decl to `strong` would indicate that you are expecting the code to be used with ARC.

Comment: It's rarely possible to write examples that are compatible with and without ARC. Most memory management code will trigger a compile error with ARC enabled (for example, `[super dealloc]` is now illegal in dealloc methods). And the last time I suggested using accessor methods on `self` inside an `init` method, I got a long list of comments telling me that's a bad idea, with some pretty strong arguments to back up their theory.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using self to access properties inside of init. Apple do it all the time. There used to be more worries about using self inside of -dealloc which does have some potential to be bad in certain cases. In this case, though, you could write this example safe for both styles or at least show you're writing for ARC by using `strong` instead of `retain`. There are still a lot of people not using ARC or not able to use ARC.